# How to bind mouse clicks to functions in all windows in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to bind the middle mouse click to a function:

```
root = Tk() 

def leftclick(self):
    print("Yep!")

root.bind("<Button-2>", leftclick)
root.mainloop()
```

This works, however only on the Tkinter window, any ideas for other windows?

Comment: What other windows?

Comment: Anything, my desktop for example. It just only registers the ones inside of the Tkinter Window

Comment: @jeffmcjeffers0n tkinter cant serve these events. You would need to write something like this. Be awere [this](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/catch_system_wide_hotkeys.html) is just a microsoft solution for example. [supports linux and windows](https://pypi.org/project/system_hotkey/)

Comment: You can only add bindings for widgets created by tkinter, and only the ones created by the program doing the binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter has no support for what you ask. Tkinter can only bind functions to windows that it creates. If you want to bind functions to events in other windows you'll have to use some platform-specific third-party library.